# App Store Connect iOS app asking for macOS option

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After the most recent AppStoreConnect update, for my iOS app, on the left side, it is asking for macOS version to be submitted in addition to iOS version.

[image]

How would I take this option out?

Comment: Click on the "1.0 prepare for submission" and then hover the mouse to get the delete button

Comment: @Paulw11 perfect! Thank you!